# class MentionStreamListener(tweepy.Stream): AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'Stream'

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-oauth

```
class MentionStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, tweet):
        if not tweet.retweeted and tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is None:
            tweet_text = tweet.text
            reply = generate_reply(tweet_text)
            reply_text = f'@{tweet.user.screen_name} {reply}'
            api.update_status(reply_text, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)
```

when running the python file the below is error getting:-

```
class MentionStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'Stream'
```

Python 3.8.10
tweepy 4.14.0

I want to make a twitter bot that reply mentioned text where reply is generated by chatgpt. I tried

from tweepy import Stream
class MentionStreamListener(Stream):

but it didn't work it show error " ImportError: cannot import name 'Stream' from 'tweepy "

Comment: That is because there is no Stream attribute in the tweepy module (https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/bb0f581f24d7d1909f40c0bf8c6be7c0c15940ba/tweepy/__init__.py). You should probably check the doc to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Stream was deprecated in v4.13 and removed with v4.14. You now have to use StreamingClient.
Try this

```
import tweepy

class MentionStreamListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
```

or you can use an older version of tweepy.

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/getting_started.html
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming.html#streaming-guide